# htaccess redirect rule throws a 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following content in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+).html$ http://www.somedomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ index\.php\?s=([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ %1?%2%3 [L,R=301]
```

This is supposed to convert queries into user friendly URLs. I had used this same htaccess on other servers before and it always worked but on some server I get a 500 error. What could be the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: check your error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. No need to include the domain name?

Comment: No domain name is needed ONLY when you are redirecting to another domain than the current one.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Im marking your answer as the right one.